# Compass not compiling in Rails 4 after Yosemite upgrade even though I am firing at root and config.rb is in root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

After I upgraded to Yosemite, Compass stopped compiling in my Rails 4 project. I am using Foundation with it (I am not sure if that makes a difference but thought I should mention it). Compass was compiling fine before the upgrade. My fils structure is as follows:

**Config.rb (located in root level of project)**

```
require 'zurb-foundation'
require 'sass-globbing'

# Change this to :production when ready to deploy the CSS to the live server.
environment = :development
#environment = :production

# Location of the theme's resources.
css_dir = "css/compiled"
sass_dir = "sass"
extensions_dir = "sass-extensions"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
#require 'ninesixty'
#require 'susy'

##
## You probably don't need to edit anything below this.
##

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = (environment == :development) ? :expanded : :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Since Drupal
# themes can be installed in multiple locations, we don't need to worry about
# the absolute path to the theme from server root.
relative_assets = true

# Pass options to sass.
# - For development, we turn on the FireSass-compatible debug_info.
# - For production, we force the CSS to be regenerated even though the source
#   scss may not have changed, since we want the CSS to be compressed and have
#   the debug info removed.
sass_options = (environment == :development) ? {:debug_info => false} : {:always_update => true}
```

**I also tried:**

```
# Location of the theme's resources.
css_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets/*"
sass_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets/*"
extensions_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets/*"
images_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets/*"
javascripts_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets/*"
```

**and this:**

```
# Location of the theme's resources.
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "."
sass_dir = "."
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
output_style = :compressed
relative_assets=true
line_comments = false
```

**compass.rb (located in my config folder)**

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :rails
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass', '3.4.5'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '~>2.11.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'
# Add Compass to the project
gem 'compass'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
# Add access to foundation classes
gem 'foundation-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  # gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
end

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'high_voltage'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'devise'
gem 'searchkick'
```

My file structure leading to the .scss files is **yelper/app/assets/stylesheets**

When I try to compile, it tells me:

```
No application integration exists for rails.
```

When I try to compile with `project_type = :rails` from compass.rb,commented out, `compass watch` does work (without tracking any files) but it tells me:

```
Compass can't find any Sass files to compile.
Is your compass configuration correct?.
If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
```

So, my confusion is because it was working just fine before the Yosemite upgrade and now it just won't work and I have no clue why. Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Does Compass installation has anything to do with Homebrew?

When I upgraded to Yosemite my PostgreSQL broke because Yosemite breaks home-brew installed applications. I had to uninstall it then re-install it.

Comment: @JoaoCunha No it doesn't. I had the same Postgres/Homebrew issue and fixed it. Compass is integrated into Rails via Ruby Gems.

Comment: No one? Really? Darn.. I am totally stumped on this..